# Timeouts on traversing from node with millions of edges

Tags: cassandra, graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I have a graph that has some nodes with millions of incident edges, using Titan 0.5.2 on top of Cassandra DB. E.g. this reproduces such graph:

```
mgmt = g.getManagementSystem()
vidp = mgmt.makePropertyKey('vid').dataType(Integer.class).make()
mgmt.buildIndex('by_vid',Vertex.class).addKey(vidp).buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.commit()

def v0 = g.addVertex([vid: 0, type: 'start'])
def random = new Random()
for(i in 1..10000000) {
  def v = g.addVertex([vid: i, type: 'claim'])
  v.addEdge('is-a', v0)
  def n = random.nextInt(i)
  def vr = g.V('vid', n).next()
  v.addEdge('test', vr) 
  if (i%10000 == 0) { g.commit(); }
}
```

So we have 10M vertices that all link to v0 and with some random links between the vertices. This query: `g.V('vid', 0).in('is-a')[0]` - works fine, and so is `g.V('vid', 0).in('is-a')[100]` or `g.V('vid', 0).in('is-a')[1000]`. However if I try to traverse further - i.e., `g.V('vid', 0).in('is-a').out('test')[0]` - then the lookup gets stuck and eventually I get read timeout exception from Cassandra:

```
com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: Could not execute operation due to backend exception

Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Could not successfully complete backend operation due to repeated temporary exceptions after Duration[4000 ms]
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.executeDirect(BackendOperation.java:86)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:42)

Caused by: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.TimeoutException: TimeoutException: [host=127.0.0.1(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=10000(10001), attempts=1]org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter.ToConnectionPoolException(ThriftConverter.java:188)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl$ThriftConnection.execute(ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl.java:
```

I also get a high load on Cassandra process and it becomes unresponsive (i.e., trying to connect to it returns timeout). So, my question is why it is impossible to traverse further from this node even though the step that actually has lots of nodes is fine - and how I could make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you have effectively simulated a supernode. When you call the function

```
g.V('vid', 0).in('is-a')[0]
```

You are only requesting one object, which is a fast lookup. Likewise:

```
g.V('vid', 0).in('is-a')[100]
```

Also only requests one object, which is still fast. When you make the query:

```
g.V('vid', 0).in('is-a').out('test')[0]
```

You've just made it request "find me all the vertices connected from the outgoing edge from the million of vertices and return the first one". The first step it will do is traverse all one million of those edges before it can return the "first" vertex you request. Try doing this:

```
g.V('vid', 0).in('is-a')[0].out('test')[0]
```

This will not iterate through all one million vertices.